# 3D model looks transparent-like

Tags: opengl

Trying to draw wavefront obj files using OpenGL but it seems there is a depth-buffer problem.

[image: Problem]

Source:

```
// Default constructor
Engine::Engine()
{
    initialize();
    loadModel();    
    start();
}

// Initialize OpenGL
void Engine::initialize()
{     
    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Enable depth write
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
}

void Engine::start()
{
    // Main loop
    while(isOpen())
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw 3D model to screen
        draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the depth test? (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`) You haven't added any code. Show us some... By the way which programming language do you use? Which is your traget platform?

Comment: Is that `init()` called after the creation of an OpenGL context? Actually those OpenGL calls in the init function don't belong there. They belong into the drawing code, right before they're needed. Move them there.

Comment: init() gets called first

Comment: What's the value of `settings.getContextSettings().depthBits`?

Comment: Do you really not use a projection matrix? You should probably have one set from gluPerspective or similar.

Comment: @genpfault 16 atm i tried different values too

Comment: Your projection matrix is identity so that represents an orthogonal projection with visible area `[-1,-1,-1]...[1,1,1]`; is that what you want? (I wonder if Z buffer's precision could cause problems here)

Comment: Are you using vertex shaders? This thing would happen if at the exit of vertex shader gl_Position.z is accidentally set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- Make sure depth test is enabled `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`
- Make sure depth write is enabled `glDepthMask(true)`
- Make sure your context has a depth buffer `Assert(glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_BITS) != 0))`

Comment: +1 for the idea, even though your syntax for `glGetIntegerv` looks off. Also I'd add `glDepthFunc` to the list (even though the default is GL_LESS which is OK)

Comment: Yeah I assume some pointer/references are needed, it was more of a pseudocode. Strangely I notice in the OpenGL 4 [reference pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) `GL_DEPTH_BITS` is no longer listed as a valid enum for glGet. I wonder if they removed it for some reason?

Comment: Yes, it's removed. I guess the idea is that if you wanted a particular bit-depth of depth, you should have asked for it in your pixel format. Or that you can just render to an FBO and blit to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Request a GL context with a depth buffer and `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`.

Try this:

```
mainWindow.create
    (
    sf::VideoMode
        (
        settings.getWidth(), 
        settings.getHeight()
        ), 
    "", 
    sf::Style::Resize,
    sf::ContextSettings( 16, 0, 0, 2, 0 )
    );
```

Comment: @genpfault 16-bit depth buffer looks a bit small for 2012 ;-) Why not 32, esp when there's no stencil?

Answer (score 1):

Did you activated the depth test?

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Where do the normals come from? Are they loaded from the OBJ file? I've had problems writing loaders that looked like this. Could it be that (assuming depth buffering is OK) *some* normals are pointing the wrong way? How about globally flipping the winding order to/from CCW. If it still looks 1/2 way solid like it does now - but in different areas, it could be that some faces are pointing the wrong way (like the surface of the table on the right) and others are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using vertex shaders? This thing would happen if at the exit of vertex shader gl_Position.z is accidentally set to 0. Or to any value between -1 and 1 I believe.

It would also happen if all vertices had equal z value before the input stage, albeit there must be something wrong with your transformation matrices in this case. Or simply you may be doing something very exotic with your transformation matrices, and the model is fine. Have you set up both MODELVIEW and PROJECTION, and multiplied them accordingly? Either in the vertex shader or in the FFP?